# Changing output format of displayed body text

Tags: 7, input-formats

I imported node and comment body fields as "Full HTML" (they are coming from a trusted site).

Now I want to display those body fields differently, for example strip certain HTML tags. Do I just change the filters for "Full HTML" and use "Full HTML" as my "custom" input format? I could change the name of it, just want to make sure it have special significance in Drupal.

Or do I have to [manually change them in the DB](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/change-the-input-format-for-3000-nodes)?

Comment: If a user doesn't have permission to edit a specific input format like Full HTML or PHP Code or whatever, they will therefore not have access to edit a node that uses that format.

Comment: To answer your first question, yea, just change the settings for your "Full HTML" filter. Nothing else magical needs to be done.

Comment: If you want to massively change your nodes' input format, you can use http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations to affect all nodes with a single UI action.

Comment: seems like I can still edit the node, just not that field. It shows a message "This field has been disabled because you do not have sufficient permissions to edit it."

Comment: How did you import the content? with a script that uses node_save() or are you using a particular module?

Comment: migrate module, it has an option for text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely make changes to the regular "Full HTML" filter. It has no special significance in the system. It is simply created by the "Standard" install profile because it is convenient for end users. If you install a minimal profile you won't have it at all.

Obviously changing the full html filter will affect other nodes as well that use this filter.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't redo the "Full HTML" filter to actually be filtered, you should add your own filter.

Try adding your custom filter, check off all the roles that can edit the content, and then disallowing the "Full HTML" for all roles.
Log in as something other than an admin role. If you resave an existing node, it should use the new filter.

Comment: thanks. Are you saying that the default "Full HTML" has a special meaning in Drupal? Couldn't I just rename it and create a new "Full HTML"?

Comment: Full html shouldn't have a special meaning to drupal no, unless some contrib module reference the full html format by id for some obscure reason. You can rename the filter and add a new full html filter, but all existing content using this filter will be affected by this change, not just your imported nodes. So the safe approach would be to add a new filter. Whether I would choose one over the other would depend on it being on a live setup or not. My point was only that altering the existing filter wasn't the only alternative.

Comment: But if you have to do this to a large number of nodes, then your method requires manually changing them all.  I'm guessing that he needs to change a lot of nodes (since I'm not sure why he would ask the question otherwise, and since he referred to a method of changing *en masse* in the database, and since he said *he imported the nodes*).