# How to bulk update text filter format on fields in drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

I have multiple fields across my site, and multiple text filters. I need to delete one of the filters, but I know that it will result in users getting that whacky permission denied error when they try to edit the field.

Is there a way to bulk update all fields input filters? I started looking at [field_update_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_field/7) in the field CRUD api, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Hi Erin, you can have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/change-the-input-format-for-3000-nodes as that method might solve your problem.  If you find a better way, please let me know ;)

Comment: Yep, that question is totally the same thing. Sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was solved in a [different question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2405/6039), the answer is below:

> Try this way, by making a loop for all nodes of certain type:
>
> ```
> $node = node_load(nid);
> $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'full_html'; // plain_text
> node_save($node);
> ```

Kudos to Ek Kosmos for sorting this out.